# (ReasonML) Regex \b not matching

Tags: regex, ocaml, reason

I'm trying out Reason and I'm trying to use a regex, but nothing is matching. AFAIK Reason doesn't have any specific regex related things so I'm just going off the OCaml documentation.

My string looks like:

```
let name = "const {foo} = bar";
```

And the regex I'm using is

```
let re = Str.regexp_string "\\bfoo\\b"
try {
  Str.search_forward re name 0;
  /* do something */
} {
 | Not_found => acc
}
```

But I'm not getting any matches. Can anyone help?

Edit: For reference, the regex docs for OCaml can be found at https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html. I was using http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_ocaml/patternmatching.html as an example for OCaml regexes I can't get it to work.

Comment: Can you post a _link_ to the page you used to find out the regex syntax it supports ? Thanks !

Comment: What about the slash after the word boundary?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"\\bfoo\\b"` with no slash at the end?

Comment: @bobblebubble
Oops, the slash at the end was a typo when I did the formatting on the question. Wasn't supposed to be there. It still doesn't work without it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks to me like you've misread the documentation. "`Str.regexp_string s` returns a regular expression that matches exactly `s` and nothing else." In other words, with your `re`, `Str.string_match re "\\bfoo\\b" 0` will return true; and your definition of `re` is equivalent to `Str.regexp "\\\\bfoo\\\\b"`. What you wanted was `Str.regexp "\\bfoo\\b"`.